# Generate arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive numbers without primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, chinese-remainder-theorem

Recently learned about this formula to generate consecutive composite numbers

$n!+2,n!+3,...,n!+n$

The goal of this question is to find if **other** methods exist to generate arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive numbers without primes.

I started searching for other formulas and stumbled upon this [Theorem 2.1](https://people.uwec.edu/mbirika/invisible_points_claim.pdf)

> For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists disjoint sets $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$
> each containing $n$ consecutive natural numbers such that $gcd(a_{1},a_{2}) > 1$ whenever $a_{i} \in A_{i}$.

If I understand it correctly, it says there are $n \times n$ hidden square forests within the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ in the plane.

For example, let $n=2$, so there's a $2 \times 2$ hidden forest with consecutive composite numbers

$174,175$

and

$20,21$

[image: hidden_forest]

For $n=4$, consecutive composites are

$2847617195518191809+1,2847617195518191809+2,...$

and

$1160906121308397397+1,1160906121308397397+2,...$

**Question**

Can those hidden consecutive points have a prime coordinate? If true, then this idea isn't valid.

If false (hurray!), is it possible to simplify the Theorem to focus on generating arbitrarily long sequences $n$ of consecutive numbers without primes?

The proof involves linear congruences and the Chinese Remainder Theorem which are far beyond my maths skills.

**EDIT**

Based upon the answers so far, this sums it up best for me

> This, of course, is impractically complicated in the context of the
> fact that you can simply generate $\{m! + k\}_{k=2}^{m}$ for $m = n^2+1$

It's a solution but is extremely computationally intractable.

For example, to generate $3$ consecutive composites, define a prime matrix

\begin{equation*}
P_{3,3} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  3 &   5 \\
7 & 11 & 13 \\
17 & 19 & 23
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The corresponding linear congruences we need to solve are

$x+1 \equiv 0 \bmod (2\times3\times5 = 30)$
$x+2 \equiv 0 \bmod (7\times11\times13 = 1001)$
$x+3 \equiv 0 \bmod (17\times19\times23 = 7429)$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem,  the unique solution is

$x =  119740619 \pmod{223092870}$

Thus, the $3$ composites are

$\Large 119740620,119740621,119740622$

Maybe other prime matrix variations work too or can be reduced to the standard [Primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).

Thanks!

Comment: This topic is referred to as "Prime Gaps" and if you search for that either on this site or google, you will find more information.

Comment: Re: techniques - if you have a known prime gap, take the product of the smallest factor of each number in the gap, then add this product to the start of the known gap - that new range will also be a prime gap. You then check before and after the new range to see if you have more composite numbers and a longer gap, if you do you repeat with your new gap, otherwise you add the product repeatedly and check the next gap. Using that technique you'll find a gap of 10 starting at 139 (btw - not a maximal gap). So that's a string of 9 composites starting at 140 and 140 is much less than 9!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction, the sets $A_1, A_2$ comprise disjoint runs of consecutive numbers, none of which can be prime because of the congruences at the top of page 7.

There is no purpose to using this theorem to generate arbitrarily long strings of consecutive composite numbers, because you already have a way to do it explicitly:  $$\{n! + k\}_{k=2}^n$$ are all composite.  The sets $A_1, A_2$ are disjoint and in general will not be consecutive with respect to each other; and within each set, the elements are indeed consecutive and composite, but their length is only $n$, rather than the full $2n$ from the union $A_1 \cup A_2$.  In fact, I think the way you asked this part of your question indicates a fundamental misunderstanding on your part.  While there are indeed $n^2$ lattice points in such a square, those are points with separate horizontal and vertical coordinates.  To get a scalar out of these points, you'd need to apply some kind of one-to-one function, say $f : \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ that preserves compositeness in the sense that if $a, b$ are composite, then $f(a,b)$ is also composite; moreover, it would also need to map the square into a set of *consecutive* composite numbers.  This, of course, is impractically complicated in the context of the fact that you can simply generate $\{m! + k\}_{k=2}^{m}$ for $m > n^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

No prime can divide a sequence of consecutive integers. For example, pick prime $p=7$. Now pick a sequence, $50,51,52,53,...$. It is not possible for 7 to divide any consecutive sequence of numbers in a row. The only numbers divisible by 7 are precisely the numbers of the form $7k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. All other numbers, $$7k+1, 7k+2, 7k+3, 7k+4, 7k+5, 7k+6$$ are relatively prime to 7.

Comment: Are you saying the hidden forest sequence cannot contain a prime because I'm worried that a point exists on the forest, something like $gcd(777,7)>1$? Is this a valid concern? If not, then hurray! Thanks.

Comment: @vengy I am confused, you appear to be stating the opposite of your question. I thought by "forest" you wanted $gcd(a,b)>1$? I just showed that that give ANY number, $n$ and a prime $p$, then it is guaranteed either $gcd(n-1,p)=1$, $gcd(n,p)=1$, or $gcd(n+1,p)=1$. So if you have a prime, you will have a gcd of 1 when compared to any consecutive sequence.

Comment: Basically, I like $gcd(a,b)>1$ but neither of them to be prime because that would break my idea about generating arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive numbers without primes. Forgive my maths ignorance, I'm a noob but appreciate your time and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

A natural way of producing such sets is to have, for each $i$ and $j$ from $1$ to $n$, a distinct prime $p_{ij}$ that divides the $i$'th member of $A_1$ and the $j$'th member of $A_2$, preventing them from being coprime.  Thus every member of both sets will end up being divisible by at least $n$ of these primes. In particular, the members of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are "very composite" in that they are divisible by many different primes.  The Chinese Remainder Theorem ensures that, given the primes $p_{ij}$, suitable $A_1$ and $A_2$ can be chosen.