# Prove that there exists a $100 \times 100$ square with no integer point visible from the origin.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> If $x$ and $y$ are integers, we say that the point $P=(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ can be seen from the origin $O=(0,0)$, if there is no other point on the line segment $OP$ whose coordinates are both integers. Prove that there exists a $100 \times 100$ square with no integer point visible from the origin.

I have a hypothesis that the only way line $\ell$ to a point $(x,y)$ does not contain any other points with integer coordinates is if $\gcd(x,y)=1$. I have not yet proven this, but I think it should help me with the problem.

I think I need to also use the Chinese remainder theorem somehow here, but I don't know in what way. I the hypothesis holds I would get pairs of integers with $\gcd$'s equal to $1$ which I can use in CRT?

Comment: Both of your ideas are correct. The proof of your first claim is not hard, try to suppose there is a point between P and O. Write the equation of the line, see what happens.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518860/generate-arbitrarily-long-sequences-of-consecutive-numbers-without-primes

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave the gcd claim to you because it's significantly easier than the rest of the problem. For the construction, I will abuse CRT.

Choose large enough primes $p_1, p_2, \cdots$. Pick $x$ such that $p_i|x$ for all $1\le i\le 100$. Pick $y$ such that $y\equiv 0\pmod{p_1}, y+1\equiv 0\pmod {p_2}, \cdots,y+99\equiv 0\pmod{p_{100}}$. Then we have that $\gcd(x,y+k)\ne 1$ for $0\le k\le 99$. Great. The trick is that we can do the exact same process again, pick the $x$ such that $p_i|x+1$ for all $101\le i\le 200$. Pick the $y$ such that $y\equiv 0\pmod{p_{101}}, \cdots, y+99\equiv 0\pmod{p_{200}}$. Choosing such $x,y$ now additionally guarantees that $\gcd(x+1, y+k)\ne 1$ for $0\le k\le 99$. Now just repeat this over and over, and you'll get the following:

Let $p_1, p_2, \cdots$ be sufficiently large primes. Pick $x$ such that $p_i|x+k$ for all $100k+1\le i\le 100k+100$ for all $0\le k\le 99$. Pick $y$ such that $y\equiv -t\pmod{p_{100r+1+t}}$ for all $0\le r\le 99$. Consider the square with vertices $(x,y), (x,y+99), (x+99, y), (x+99, y+99)$.

Comment: I think the idea of the construction can be simplified by considering a $100 \times 100$ matrix $P$ of distinct primes (where index counting starts at $(0,0)$) then choose $x$ such that for each $0 \le j < 100$ $x+j$ is a multiple of all primes of the $j$-th column of $P$. Chose $y$ such that for each $0\le i < 100$ $y+i$ is a multiple of the $i$-th row of $P$. Then each point $(x+j, y+i)$ is "blocked from view" by $((x+j)/p_{i,j}, (y+i)/p_{i,j})$.

Comment: How did you come up with the idea here? I tried to plot some of the points which cannot be seen from the origin and determine whether they leave a square of size $n \times n$, but I don't think there is any pattern to this. @TheBestMagician

Comment: A small grid array can be found by hand, computer search will go a bit further. But if you look at the solutions the starting x coordinate of the grid has to to be divisible by products of many numbers, so they will likely have > 100 decimal digits. Then x+1 needs to be divisible by another big number of > 100 decimal digits and this goes on. That means an estimate for the $x$ coordinate is around $10^{10000}$. 

If you solve a lot of problems involving consecutive numbers being divisible by something, you know the Chinese Remainder theorem is very likely the way to go.

Comment: Well I just worked one row at a time. I just constructed it in a way so that a common prime divisor is always formed. For example, I needed a prime dividing x and y+1, then I needed one for x and y+2, etc. Writing modular congruences and slightly modifying so that solutions exist by CRT, I got the construction.